# Is this scalac bug?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, classcastexception, partialfunction

```scala
class X[A](val value: A){
  def unapply[B <: A](x: X[B]) = true
}

object Main extends App {
  val int = new X(1)
  val string = new X("a")
  val pf: PartialFunction[Any, Int] = { case o @ int() => o.value }
  println(pf(string) + 1)
}
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
```

I think <del>this code should throw a `MatchError` instead of `ClassCastException`. or</del> scalac should warn this code.

Scala 2.11.5

**Edited:**

Scala 2.9.3 warn follows. but not 2.10, 2.11

```
Main.scala:8: warning: non variable type-argument B in type pattern X[B] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
  val pf: PartialFunction[Any, Int] = { case o @ int() => o.value }
                                                    ^
```

I am understanding type erasure from the beginning.

In other word, `pf.isDefinedAt(string)` returns true but `pf.apply(string)` throws `ClassCastException`

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_67).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class X[A](val value: A){
  def unapply[B <: A](x: X[B]) = true
}

val int = new X(1)
val string = new X("a")
val pf: PartialFunction[Any, Int] = { case o @ int() => o.value }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class X
int: X[Int] = X@4f3cb3fc
string: X[String] = X@1a4c8e08
pf: PartialFunction[Any,Int] = <function1>

scala> pf.isDefinedAt(string)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> pf.apply(string)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
  ... 33 elided
```

Comment: Looks like type erasure problem, Scala can't distinguish between `X[Int]` and `X[String]`, so match is positive, but function return type is `Int` while value is `String`.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Any` is a big smell in the code. You can't fault the compiler when you just threw away your type information.

First, I'd replace `Any` with `X[C]`:

```
def pf[C]: PartialFunction[X[C], Int] = { case o @ int() => o.value }
```

This gives the following compilation error:

```
[error] Foo.scala:12: inferred type arguments [C] do not conform to method unapply's type parameter bounds [B <: Int]
[error]   def pf[C]: PartialFunction[X[C], Int] = { case o @ int() => o.value }
[error]                                                      ^
```

If you want to delay the typechecking till the runtime, you need to capture the type information somewhere. We can do this in `X` as follows:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class X[A: TypeTag](val value: A) {
  val typeTag = typeOf[A]
  def unapply[B](x: X[B]): Boolean =
    x.typeTag <:< this.typeTag
}
```

Now we have to tell the compiler that if match succeeds `C` is actually `Int`.

```
def pf[C]: PartialFunction[X[C], Int] = { case o @ int() => o.value.asInstanceOf[Int] }
println(pf(int) + 1)  
println(pf(string) + 1)
```

This seems to work:

```
[info] Running Main 
2
[error] (run-main-7) scala.MatchError: X@1c34aaaa (of class X)
scala.MatchError: X@1c34aaaa (of class X)
```

Answer (score 0):

They went to great lengths:

```
scala> import reflect._
import reflect._

scala> class X[A: ClassTag](val v: A) { def unapply[B <: A](x: X[B]) = x.v match {
     |   case _: A => true
     |   case _    => false } }
defined class X

scala> val int = new X(1)
int: X[Int] = X@2a5ca609

scala> val s = new X("a")
s: X[String] = X@4667ae56

scala> val pf: PartialFunction[Any, Int] = { case o @ int() => o.v }
pf: PartialFunction[Any,Int] = <function1>

scala> pf(s)
scala.MatchError: X@4667ae56 (of class X)
  at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:253)
  at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:251)
  at $anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:12)
  at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
  ... 33 elided

scala> pf(int)
res1: Int = 1
```

But I guess you mean, if they complain about this statically, why don't they insert an instanceof test for me? At least when they can?

```
scala> val pf: PartialFunction[X[_], Int] = { case o @ int() => o.v }
<console>:12: error: inferred type arguments [_$1] do not conform to method unapply's type parameter bounds [B <: Int]
       val pf: PartialFunction[X[_], Int] = { case o @ int() => o.v }
                                                       ^
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : _1
 required: Int
       val pf: PartialFunction[X[_], Int] = { case o @ int() => o.v }
                                                                  ^
```